kdewallet just suddenly stopped working, how to recover?
Sometime over the last couple of days, kdewallet just stopped working. I'm not sure what this coincided with, but it might be related to installing VirtualBox, which for some reason involved installing a new Secure Boot MOK on the host. Just suddenly, I started getting prompts for a password to open kdewallet, and my password was not accepted. I have not changed my password. I still have the .kwl and .salt files that stopped working. Is there any way to decrypt them?
